# Is there a solidity library to create msgHash?

Tags: solidity, dapps

Messages are hashed with a “\x19Ethereum Signed Message” for some reason. I'm writing a smart contract that authenticates a message to a signature, and it needs to be able to generate msgHash to do that. Is there a library for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few libraries which should be helpful for what you are trying to accomplish (including handling the “\x19Ethereum Signed Message”). See below link for a more up-to-date library which is quite useful.

[ECTools Gist](https://gist.github.com/axic/5b33912c6f61ae6fd96d6c4a47afde6d#gistcomment-2359559)